# Move git history of deleted file which was actually renamed

Tags: git, github, move

Git. How can I move history of deleted and pushed file to current file in branch.

I've migrated project to typescript but some files were not marked as git-moved but deleted and then new added, there are several commits and pushes so now I have properly migrated project but some migrated files miss their history.

Comment: There is no *file history* in a Git repository. The history in a Git repository consists of the commits in the Git repository (connected through their parent commit linkage). Each commit has a full snapshot of all files. If you ask Git about one file, what it does is look through all the *commits*, comparing parent and child, and then only *tells you* about commits in which the particular pairwise comparison says that this one file is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new branch from a commit just before the migration started.
2. Perform the migration steps again, using git properly this time.
3. Cherry-pick the commits you want on top, from the old branch to the new.
4. Reset the old branch to match the new.
5. Force push (assuming you have already pushed the old one).
6. Tell any collaborators that their next pull will be painful.

Comment: So I have to manually migrate again but respect file migration. Almost every commit has such file so no way that could be fast. I thought there might be a way like **git mv** history from old branch

Comment: By "every commit" do you mean the new work since the migration? Those should cherry-pick just fine, IIUC, or else "git format-patch; git am" should work (the text inside the files will be identical).